# If Spark SQL support HQL like 'insert overwrite directory'?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to ask if Spark SQL support HQL like 'insert overwrite directory'.
Or is there another way to save the Result set（from a spark sql jdbc server） to HDFS directly?

Comment: Which spark version are you using @Locki Yang

Answer (score 0):

There is one jira for this issue which is not yet resolved the jira link for that is https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4131 . But you can do something like this:

```
    JavaSchemaRDD employeeSchemaRDD = context.sql("SELECT * FROM employee");

    JavaRDD<String> strRDD=employeeSchemaRDD.map(new Function<Row, String>() {

        public String call(Row row) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return row.get(1).toString();
        }

    });
strRDD.saveAsTextFile("outputdir");
```

Replace outputdir with HDFS url where you want to write the output.
Hope this answer you question.